# breadcrumb for different taxonomies

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have the following setup: On my site users can publish ads to sell things. Each ad has at least two taxonomy terms assigned:

- Region
- Category

Sometimes users navigate via region to a specific ad, sometimes the users navigates via Categoryto a specific ad. Finally the user clicks on the ad and the ad is shown.
Now I want to display a breadcrumb, and this should depend on the way the user navigated down.

Example 1:
If the user has chosen to see a list of regions and then presses "California" he sees all ads. Then he clicks on the ad 988. The breadcrumb now should be:

home>California

Example 2:
If the user has chosen to see a list of categories and then presses "cars" he sees all ads in this category. Then he clicks on the ad 988. The breadcrumb now should be:

home>Cars

Is there a way to complete this?
Or is there a way to create a breadcrumb for the two cases above like that:
home>California>Cars?

thanks for any help and information

Comment: The [Crumbs module](https://drupal.org/project/crumbs) should be able to handle that with the built in plugins

Comment: thanks, I did not know this module. I will check it out

Comment: Bit of advice: that module might seem a bit daunting and incomprehensible at first. Take the time to read the docs before you play around with it, so you know what to expect from the UI. It's a ridiculously powerful module, so even if you can't get quite what you want out of the box, by writing a small plugin and chaining it with existing ones, you'll be able to get anything you want